# How do I calculate distance?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to calculate distance, so like. "If (object 10 pixels or less close to this object)" or like (object 10 pixels or more far to this object)

Is there a good way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the distance on each axis first, and then form a triangle between them using pythagorean theorem:

```
var p1:Point = new Point(0,0);
var p2:Point = new Point(3,4);

//distance on the x axis
var dx = p2.x - p1.x; //3

//distance on the y axis
var dy = p2.y - p1.y; //4

//c^2 = a^2 + b^2
var distance = Math.sqrt( (dy * dy) + (dx * dx) ); //5
```

Here is a function you can use to do this

```
function getDistance(p1:Point, p2:Point):Number
{
    var dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    var dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    return Math.sqrt( (dy * dy) + (dx * dx) );
}
```

Comment: Or the easiest: Point.distance() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#distance%28%29

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to use the static method distance (Returns the distance between pt1 and pt2) of the class [Point](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html).
I also recommend you also to check some useful methods as distance, interpolate and so on.

```
var p1:Point = new Point(0,0);
var p2:Point = new Point(3,4);

trace(Point.distance(p1, p2)); // 5
```